# Execute a python script through php by opening the Windows command line

Tags: php, python, cmd

I've finished writing my Python script and it works perfectly fine in the command line.

My code:

```
#!C:/Python36/python
import csv
import sys
import cgi
import cgitb
import re
import webbrowser

cgitb.enable()

data = {i[0]:i[1:] for i in csv.reader(open('students.csv'))}
data2 = {j[0]:j[1:] for j in csv.reader(open('subjects.csv'))}

i = 0
while i == 0:
    Name = input("Please provide your name (q to quit): ")
    if Name == 'q':
        i = 1
    else:
        Subject = input("Please provide your Subject: ")
        if Subject in data[Name]:
            if Subject in data2.keys():
                print ("you are registered - your VM is)
                url = str(data2[Subject])
                url2 = re.search("(?P<url>https?://[^\s]+)", url).group("url")
                url2 = url2[:-2]
                webbrowser.open(url2)
            else:
                print("The VM for the subject doesn't exist")
        else:
            print("you are not registered")
```

The last step I need to do is to adjust this script to my web interface. I do not really familiar with php so I cannot really rewrite this script in php so I've tried to execute this script directly from php to make it work in browser by using:

```
<?php 
$command = escapeshellcmd('python C:\\wamp64\\wwww\\test.py');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;
?>
```

or

```
<?php 
echo shell_exec('python c:\\wamp64\\www\\test.py');
?>
```

The first one does not show anything, whereas the second one gives me an error because of "input" function so I've tried this:

```
<?php 
$Name = '';
echo shell_exec('python c:\\wamp64\\www\\test.py $Name');
?>
```

It did not work still.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAkQw.jpg)

I analysed similar question but did not really find a solution. Because of that, I came up with the solution - when I press "Submit" button, it should open Windows command line for me. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzEBo.jpg)

The second php code, which uses shell_exec, should work but apparently it does not work because of compatibility issues between python and php.
By the way, I set up all the permissions and system path for the python script
I've searched a lot for the solution but it was not really successful.

Could you please give me any ideas or maybe it is possible to make "input" function properly with php?

Thank you.